# Python - Obtain indices of intersecting values in two arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy

If I have two arrays:

```
A=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]  
B=[2,4,7]
```

I would like to obtain an array `C` that contains the indices of the the values of `B` also found in `A`

```
C=[1,3,6]
```

I'm quite new to Python and I'm frustrated of not being able to find an elegant solution to such a simple task without the need of using a loop combined with `numpy.where()`.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: In your example, every value in B is also present in A. Will that always be the case?

Comment: What should the output be if a `B` element is not in `A`? e.g. `B = [2,44,7]`? Also, what if it's present in multiple locations in `A`? Or are `A` entries unique?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a linear-time solution: to efficiently test whether an element is in B, convert it to a set first.

```py
B_set = set(B)
C = [i for i, x in enumerate(A) if x in B_set]
```

For large inputs, this is better than using `.index` in a loop, since that requires repeatedly searching the list in O(mn) time, where m and n are the size of A and B. In comparison, the solution above takes O(m + n) time to convert to a set and then build the result list.

Comment: This is better than Guy's approach as `.index` only returns the index of 1st occurrence of the number. If you have duplicates and want a linear time this solution is better.+1

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`np.isin`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html?highlight=numpy%20isin#numpy.isin) and [`np.nonzero`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html).

```
a=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
b=np.array([2,4,7])
c=np.nonzero(np.isin(a,b))[0]
# array([1, 3, 6], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: Do you know the time complexity of `np.isin` for this? I don't see it in the documentation.

Comment: @HeapOverflow I found this on Numpy documentation. *isin(a, b) is roughly equivalent to np.array([item in b for item in a])* It's equivalent to `O(m*n)`.

Comment: I wouldn't assume from that part of the docs that it's O(mn) - often docs will give an "equivalent" expression to explain what the behaviour/output is, but that doesn't mean it's equivalent in implementation.

Comment: Well, it says "roughly", and "equivalent" might just refer to the result, not to the efficiency.

Comment: From the looks of it, there is [an open pull request](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/12065) to improve the performance of `np.isin` by using a bit array to test membership, though that doesn't necessarily imply the current performance is asymptotically worse.

Comment: @kaya3 Frustrating to see them have such a long discussion but never talk about complexity (as far as I saw). Anyway, did [a test](https://repl.it/repls/GracefulNoisyScreencast) that says it would be 160 billion comparisons per second, which can't be true.

Answer (score 2):

There is a special function in the `numpy` module for this, [`intersect1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html) by passing `True` in its `return_indices` argument you get indices of the intersection.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
b = np.array([2,4,7])
c = np.intersect1d(a, b, return_indices=True)[1]
# array([1, 3, 6], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: I thought your answer was faster than mine. What do you think the reason is?

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over `B` and use `index()` on `A` with the values

```
c = [A.index(i) for i in B]
```

As per of @kaya3's comment you can add a check if the value of `B` present in `A` in case it can contain non existing values

```
c = [A.index(i) for i in B if i in A]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the index function.

```
A = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
B = [2,4,7]
C = [a.index(b) for b in B]
C = list(map(lambda b: a.index(b),B)
```